# How to use Google Tag Manager with multiple Google Analytics accounts

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I'm trying to find a way to duplicate all of my Google Tag Manager tags that send information to Google Analytics to also send the information to a second GA account. From what I understand, using multiple tags that track events and record the data to separate GA accounts will result in duplicated data. I can add a separate GTM container to my site and change the data layer name, but then I'll need to manually copy over all of the tags for the new container. Is there an easier way to do this? Ideally I would just add the second GA account info to each tag, but there doesn't seem to be any way to do that.

Comment: Have you tried creating a comma separated list inside the Tag?

Answer (score 2):

You are not able to send the hit data to two different GA properties at once. [See here](https://www.sitevisibility.co.uk/blog/2016/07/12/track-multiple-google-analytics-properties-gtm-google-tag-manager/)

> Fortunately, king of GTM, Simo Ahava replied to my help thread and confirmed my thinking – you can’t track multiple GA properties in one GTM tag.

What you can do is create 2x Pageview tags, each with it's own GA Settings variable and UA ID. 
The same is true for Event tags etc
Your container will just become a bit cluttered if you have allot of tags.

That looks like the only way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Universal Analytics? According to Google this should not cause you problems:

> You can, for example, install multiple instances of the Universal
>   Analytics tracking code (analytics.js) on your web pages but only one
>   instance of the Classic Analytics code (ga.js).

Source: https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1032400?hl=en

If ga.js, consider upgrading, or go for the easier way - Give different users access to different properties which show data according to filters.